# NSUnknownKeyException while using SearchBar. this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsarray, searchbar, nsunknownkeyexception

I've had a look through posts that other people have posted with this sort of error, but non in a `UISearchBar`, and none that I can relate my issue to:

In short, I'm playing with searchBars and trying to build the basics.

I have 2 arrays

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *dataList;
    NSArray *searchResults;
}
```

I've populated my dataList array using the following:

```
dataList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[dataList addObject:@"This is row 1"];
[dataList addObject:@"That is row 2"];
....
[dataList addObject:@"More data in 20"];
```

I set up my `searchDisplayController`:

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString*) searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                           scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                  objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
    return YES;
}
```

and I have a filter function:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {    
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];

    searchResults = [dataList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

It's in the last filter function that I get an error on the last line beginning `searchResults =`

```
2014-07-29 17:47:16.056 TestSearch[44628:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFConstantString 0x1000069c8> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'
*** First throw call stack:
...
...
...
```

Any ideas?

I have tried using an `NSArray` instead of `NSMutableArray` but I get the same error.

The `tableView` is filling up OK with the data, so no problem there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`name` is not a property of an `NSString` object. use `self` for the predicate:

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self contains[c] %@", searchText];
```

Comment: Thank you.  I had been looking at that for hours and didn't see it.